# What is the radius of convergence of the following series?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

**PROBLEM**

Determine the radius of convergence of
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}}.$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

Is this
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}}$$
even a power series?  After all, we have defined power series to take the form
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{{a_n}(z - c)^n}$$
where $\{a_n\}$ is a complex sequence and $c \in \mathbb{C}$ is called the center of the series.

Now, if I consider
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}}$$
to be a power series, then setting
$$b_n := \bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}$$
I get
$$\left|\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\right|=\left|\frac{(z+1)^{(n+1)^2}}{(3-i)^{(n+1)^2}}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{(3-i)^{n^2}}{(z+1)^{n^2}}\right|=\left|\frac{(z+1)^{2n+1}}{(3-i)^{2n+1}}\right|=\left|\frac{(z+1)^{2n}}{(3-i)^{2n}}\right|\cdot\left|\frac{z+1}{3-i}\right|.$$

*So this is not the correct approach.*

Now, if I use the Cauchy-Hadamard Formula for the radius of convergence $R$, I get
$$\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\left|b_n\right|^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\left|\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}\right|^{1/n} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\sup\left|\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^n\right| = \infty.$$

Consequently, $R = 0$.

In other words,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}}$$
converges absolutely only at $z = -1$, so that
$$\text{Radius of convergence } = 0$$
and
$$\text{Domain of convergence } = \left\{-1\right\}.$$

**QUESTION**

> Is my attempt at determining the radius of convergence correct?  If not, where is the error and how can it be mended?

Comment: For a less long-winded approach note that $\sum_n w^{n^2}$ converges if $|w|<1$ and diverges if $|w|>1$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @LordSharktheUnknown!  Posting an answer in a bit, I hope it is correct!  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking cue from the hint in the comments,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{z+1}{3-i}\bigg)^{n^2}}$$
converges if
$$\left|\frac{z+1}{3-i}\right| < 1,$$
which implies that
$$\left|z+1\right| < \left|3-i\right| = \sqrt{10}.$$
Hence, the radius of convergence is
$$R = \sqrt{10}.$$